# How does rounding affect Fibonacci-ish sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, linear-transformations, dynamical-systems, approximation

I'm curious how one might account for rounding in simple recurrence relations.

$\textbf{Explanation}$

For a specific problem, suppose we have a sequence of positive integers $a_1, a_2, a_3,...$ with where each $a_i$ obeys the following rule
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+\text{floor}\Big[\frac{a_{n-4}}{2}\Big]$$
Where "floor" here just means round down. For example if $a_1=5$ and $a_4=7$ then
$$a_5=7+\text{floor}\Big[\frac{5}{2}\Big]=9$$

And if we start with $a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=6$ and continue the sequence we get
$$6\rightarrow6\rightarrow6\rightarrow6\rightarrow9\rightarrow12\rightarrow15\rightarrow18\rightarrow22\rightarrow28\rightarrow35\rightarrow44\rightarrow55\rightarrow...$$
What is $a_{100}$? And more importantly, can $a_n$ in general be exactly calculated without calculating all the previous terms in the sequence?

Here's what's been tried so far

$\textbf{Linear Algebra Approximation}$

The update rule for the previous sequence can be approximated with a linear transformation
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad \quad \text{with} \quad \quad
A \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
a_n \\
b_n \\
c_n \\
d_n \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{n+1} \\
b_{n+1} \\
c_{n+1} \\
d_{n+1} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where the $a_n$ in each vector corresponds to the same $a_n$ of the previous sequence example.

This matrix has only one all-positive eigenvector with an eigenvalue $\lambda=1.254...$ which is the growth rate approached by the sequence. One could predict the value of $a_n$ by calculating
$$A^n \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \\
a_1 \\
a_1 \\
a_1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

The problem with using a linear transformation is that rounding isn't taken into account. So the predictions one gets inevitably overshoot. And some starting sequences don't even increase when rounding is taken into account. Consider $a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=1$
$$1\rightarrow1\rightarrow1\rightarrow1\rightarrow1\rightarrow1\rightarrow1\rightarrow1\rightarrow...$$

$\textbf{Error Estimation}$

For initial values of the sequence that highly divisible by $2$, the rounding down won't affect the sequence for a longer time.

More specifically if we start with
$$a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=k2^m \text{ where } k \text{ is odd}$$
Then $a_{4m+5}$ will be the first term affected by the rounding.
One could introduce a rounding error function. Something of the form
$$f(k, m) = \text{% error approached by the initial value } k2^m$$

It was suggested to use linear dynamical discrete systems to derive an exact formula for $a_n$. How exactly that is done is still unknown. Are there any good example problems similar to this one?

Comment: I'll admit, I don't get the matrix stuff: you can make recurrence relations like $a_n=a_{n-2}+a_{n-4}$ into Fibonacci like ones with $a_1=a_2;a_2=a_4;a_n=a_{2n}$ ,for example. with you example relation we get the following:

$$a_{17}\mapsto(a_{16},a_{13})\mapsto(a_{15},a_{12},a_9)\mapsto(a_{14},a_{11},a_8,a_5)\mapsto(a_{13},a_{10},a_7,a_4,a_1)\mapsto(a_{13},a_{12},a_{10},a_9,a_7,a_6,a_4,a_3,a_1) $$ so sure in theory you can know a smaller subset but it takes more work from them to get to it and in effect calculating through all them if you do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific question about calculating $a_n$ **exactly** without calculating **all** the previous terms, the answer is no, in general, unless you are really lucky. In your specific case, if the modulo $2$ behavior of the sequence were periodic then you might have a hope, but it is not.