# Finding a quadruplet of "cow-equivalent" integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, rounding-error

This a follow up question/puzzle from an earlier question here [How does rounding affect Fibonacci-ish sequences?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2365431/how-does-rounding-affect-fibonacci-ish-sequences)

**Explanation**

For this new question, one needs only to understand a particular transformation

$$
f\big(
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\b\\c\\d
\end{bmatrix}\big)
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a+\text{floor}(\frac{d}{2})\\a\\b\\c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So for example, this sequence is generated by repeatedly applying the transformation
$$
\begin{bmatrix}5\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}5\\5\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}5\\5\\5\\0\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}5\\5\\5\\5\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}7\\5\\5\\5\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}9\\7\\5\\5\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}11\\9\\7\\5\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}13\\11\\9\\7\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}16\\13\\11\\9\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\ ...
$$
Because the function rounds down $d$, it's very hard to predict the exact values after many iterations. Interestingly though -- certain initial values eventually converge to the same sequence

For example if we continue the sequence above
$$
\cdots\ 
\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}16\\13\\11\\9\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}20\\16\\13\\11\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}25\\20\\16\\13\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}31\\25\\20\\16\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}39\\31\\25\\20\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}49\\39\\31\\25\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\ \cdots
$$
And compare it to the sequence of another initial value
$$
\begin{bmatrix}9\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}9\\9\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\ \cdots \ \rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}25\\21\\17\\13\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}31\\25\\21\\17\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}39\\31\\25\\21\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}49\\39\\31\\25\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\ \cdots
$$
The sequences hit the same point. More specifically, we will say that
$$
f^{13}\big(\begin{bmatrix}5\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\big)
=
f^{10}\big(\begin{bmatrix}9\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\big)
$$
This means the sequence for $5$ and the sequence for $9$ will be the same as each other if continued further.

I've been calling numbers like this "cow-equivalent" because this iteration models the population growth of animals in Minecraft – when bred every 5 minutes by the player. A related-but-simpler transformation is also discussed here [Exponential growth of cow populations in Minecraft](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077825/exponential-growth-of-cow-populations-in-minecraft)

Here we'll use the "$\equiv$" symbol to denote cow-equivalency. So
$$a\equiv b \quad\text{if and only if there exists}\quad m, n \in \mathbb{N}$$
$$\text{ such that}$$
$$f^m(a\cdot\vec{e_1})=f^n(b\cdot\vec{e_1})$$

**Questions**

A quick computer search shows that there are triplets of cow-equivalent numbers like
$$34\equiv 259\equiv 406$$
because
$$f^{35}(\begin{bmatrix}34\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix})=
f^{26}(\begin{bmatrix}259\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix})=
f^{24}(\begin{bmatrix}406\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix})=
\begin{bmatrix}113171\\90268\\72000\\57429\end{bmatrix}$$
Thus the primary question here is

- Does a quadruplet of cow-equivalent numbers exist?

Other interesting/related questions

- Are all numbers potentially cow-equivalent?
- Is the triplet above – or any other cow-equivalence set – complete?
- Is there a deterministic test one can apply for cow-equivalence?

Comment: Your solution for triplets isn't complete, I could find solutions $f^{17}(11) = f^{15}(17) = f^{14}(21),\quad 
f^{29}(2) = f^{28}(3) = f^{17}(27),\quad 
f^{37}(41) = f^{36}(51) = f^{27}(384),\quad 
f^{38}(34) = f^{29}(259) = f^{27}(406).$

Comment: He did not claim those were all triplets, he merely said that there are triplets, and exhibited one to prove his point.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I had to read it because I wanted to see whether cow-equivalent was a typo. :). Good Q.

Comment: I haven't been able to find additional triplets (let alone quadruplets), but for what it's worth it appears there are pairs of (arbitrarily?) distant cow-equivalent numbers. For instance, you can check $20328$ and $306565$ are cow-equivalent.